# How do I preserve a downloaded PWA which is not available online anymore?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have a downloaded PWA in Chrome which works fine, but the original website is gone.  Is there a way to preserve and share a PWA so that others can enjoy it too?

<sub>The website is `luaplanter.com`, from an [indiegogo campaign](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/lua-the-smart-planter-with-feelings) which was quickly abandoned by the author, leaving owners of the device unable to configure it. I have [added parts of the source code and example QR codes in a repo](https://github.com/henrik242/lua-planter-findings)</sub>